# Is the 100% featured character chance carried over in the new banner in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

According to the pity system in Genshin Impact, in the featured character banner, you are bound to get a 5* character within 90 wishes and if that character is not a featured character, then the next 5* character you will get in the same banner is bound to be the featured character.

Now, my question is, if my last 5* character in the featured character banner (Xiao banner) is not the featured character (Mona), will my next 5* character in the new banner (upcoming Zhongli banner) will have a 100% chance to be the featured character? Or do I have another 50% chance for the feature character (Zhongli) again?

Note that 4 feature banners have past since I got my last 5* in this banner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the pity status is carried to the next limited character banner.
So, in this case, you are bound to get the Geo Archeon because of the 100% limited character pity since your previous one was a standard pool one.

For reference, take the text in Venti banner

> For Event Wish "Ballad in Goblets": Base probability of winning 5-star character = 0.600%; consolidated probability (incl. guarantee) = 1.600%; guaranteed to win 5-star character at least once per 90 attempts. The first time you win a 5-star item in this event wish, there is a 50% chance it will be the promotional character "Windborne Bard" Venti (Anemo). If the first 5-star character you win in this event wish is not the promotional character, then the next 5-star character you win is guaranteed to be the promotional character.

The description is indeed unclear but the meaning is that banners of the same class - so Limited/Weapon/Standard - share the same pity counter.
So, if for example you are on 50/90 when Venti banner ends, the pity counter for the **Limited** character banner will still be 50/90 on the next one. The 50/50 vs guaranteed pity class carries over to.

Now the real question is... Zhongli or Lady End User License Agreement?

Comment: I am also going with the same notion (and also have the same expansion in my head each time I see her name XD). Since I already have Ganyu, Zhongli will have my primogems, then “I will have order!”

Comment: @SnowWolf trust me, basically every mention of the pity system I saw agrees on this point - you are safe on your pull - what you should fear is too many characters you like in too few weeks - some say Klee could be getting a rerun soon, for example. As for the Eula, I saw that meme and found it quite fun to use.

Comment: Yes, I got him, the minute the banner was released! Rex Lapis is mine! Your answer is proven correct!

Answer (score -2):

From my experience, it does not guarantee 50/50 does not carry over. Everyone says that it does, but it isn't true. This happened to me. Later I contacted mihoyo support, and said that all over the Internet people think it does. They said sorry it doesn't

Comment: Do you have proof of either the claim, or the conversation with support? This runs counter to multiple large data projects.